# Nextjs not able to receive data from expressjs API in correct format

Tags: express, next.js

ive got a page which i call an api through getserversideprops to basically get all the data from a table. it used to work fine, but suddenly when i runned it today an error occured which i dont know the cause is. this is the response im getting when i console log the response
[image]

what i tried on my own and noticed to "help" was reducing the amount of columns that the API was selecting. For the api i used knex and express. this was the original code that used to work but now does not.

```
 try{
        let data = "";
        await db.transaction(async (t)=>{
            data = await db('sales').transacting(t)
            .join('users','users.id','sales.cashier_id')
            .join('customer','customer.customer_id','sales.customer_id')
            .select('customer.name as customer_name','sales.sales_id','sales.date','sales.payment_type','sales.payment_status','sales.customer_id','sales.transaction_total','sales.total_paid','users.name','sales.shipment_fee','sales.days','sales.sale_type')
           
        })
        return data
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        throw e;
    }
```

what i tried was reducing the amount of select columns to i think 5 or 6, but definitely if the amount of columsn i use is under a limit it works. like

```
 try{
        let data = "";
        await db.transaction(async (t)=>{
            data = await db('sales').transacting(t)
            .join('users','users.id','sales.cashier_id')
            .join('customer','customer.customer_id','sales.customer_id')
             .select('customer.name as customer_name','sales.sales_id','sales.transaction_total','sales.date','sales.payment_type')
        })
        return data
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        throw e;
    }
```

these are the attributes of my table
[image]

this is the server.js file of my expressjs

```
const compression = require('compression');
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http')
const https =  require('https')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000;
var cors = require('cors')
const mainRoutes = require('./api/v1/routes/index')
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

app.use(compression());
app.use(cors( {origin: 'http://localhost:3000',credentials: true}))
// app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
// app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());


// Main Routes
app.use("/api/v1", mainRoutes,(req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

this is how im calling the api from next

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    try{
        const res = await axios.get("/sales/get-all");     
        const data = await  res.data
     return { props: { data } }
    }catch(err){
      const data = "error"
      return { props: { data} }
    }
      
    
    }
```

where i declared default url of the axios at the app.js file of next

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/"

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

im not quite sure what the problem is so pardon if the title of the question is not according to the problem i have.

EDIT:
i moved the api to a useeffect call, its now working. but why isnt it working in getserversideprops?

Comment: just additional information, everything else works for the get all api's that i use. only in the get all of sales where i joined a few tables and needed to select alot of columns that this error occured. and the response i get is fine when i try it out in postman

Comment: when i query only 1 row it works fine, but when i query something that results in 4 rows. the error upholds